# Where can I go to make progress after defeating Bloodless?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

I defeated Bloodless, got her shard, and now I think I have explored every area I can access, and I haven't found anything that looks like it allows me to make more progress. What should I be looking for, and where should I be looking? The main barriers to progress seem to be doors that require keys I don't have, and water that I can't dive in in the Forbidden Underground Waterway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Blood Steal shard from Bloodless, you can absorb the blood in the fountain near the castle entrance. That gives access to a new part of the Forbidden Underground Waterways. Down there, a jellyfish-like enemy drops a shard that allows you to swim in the water, which you can use to access more areas and make progress.

Comment: Took me a good while to figure that out too.

Comment: I actually figured out the fountain thing before asking the question. But I didn't think of killing enemies in the water to look for a shard like that. I only went back to kill them because one of the quests asked me to and I decided to try finishing quests while waiting for an answer.